# Using embedding layer with GRU

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I have a working code using GRU creating the input manually as a 3D array (None,10,64). The code is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(300, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(None, 64)))
model.add(Dropout(0.8)) 
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=300))       
model.add(Activation("linear"))
```

This returns the predicted embedding given the input window. Now I want to use the keras embedding layer on top of GRU. My idea is to input a 2D array (None, 10) and use the embedding layer to convert each sample to the corresponding embedding vector.

So now I have this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 64, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=10, trainable=False))
model.add(GRU(300, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.8)) 
model.add(Dense(64))  
model.add(Activation("linear"))
```

I see from the summary that the output of the embedding layer is:

```
embedding_2 (Embedding)      (None, 10, 64)
```

which is what I expected. But when I try to fit the model I get this error:

```
expected activation_2 to have shape (64,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

If I comment the other layers and leave only the embedding and gru I get:

```
expected gru_5 to have shape (300,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

So my question is what is the difference between fitting a manually constructed 3D array and an embedding layer generated one?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model reflects the desired computation; however, the error is `Y` you are passing to the model. You are passing a scalar target instead of an array of size `(64,)`. To clarify your inputs should be sequence of integers, but your targets still need to be vectors.

Also, `Dense` by default has linear activation, so you don't need the `Activation('linear')` after `Dense(64)`.